# How to disable tqdm progress bars appearing in an algorithm by default

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, forecasting, tqdm, facebook-prophet

I need to disable the progress bar that is appearing by default while training the Neuralprophet algorithm.
[image: I basically need to hide these2 green progress bar]

Sample code to try:

```
import pandas as pd
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet, set_log_level
set_log_level("ERROR")

data_location = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ourownstory/neuralprophet-data/main/datasets/"
df = pd.read_csv(data_location + "air_passengers.csv")
#df.tail(3)

m = NeuralProphet(n_lags=5, n_forecasts=3)
metrics_train = m.fit(df=df, freq="MS",progress='print')
```

Comment: Have you tried `progress="none"`? This value appears undocumented, but the [source code](https://github.com/ourownstory/neural_prophet/blob/e57badfcb1459ad52c338d69e54a5d43831f90e9/neuralprophet/forecaster.py#L2036) suggests that might work.

Comment: I tried progress='none' but it didn't help
`metrics_train = m.fit(df=df, freq="MS", progress='none')`